# Laptop does not start anymore because of power issues

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power

I had power issues with my laptop (HP Pavilion dv7 1040ef) for awhile (two dead accumutators, some shutdowns for no reason), but now my computer won't load anymore. I can still start it on accumutators, but it will probably run out of power in a few minutes).
When I unplugged the AC adapter while the battery was in and then replugged it, it often kept running, then shut down an hour later.

There is a LED (on the computer, next to the cable) that should glow when charging, but plugging the AC adapter does not make it glow. It sometimes blinks once when I unplug the cable.
If I unplug the AC adapter from the wall, its LED (on the adapter) keeps glowing for a while, suggesting computer does not even draw power from it.

It has already happen several time, but I managed to get through with trying different (random) procedures (none of them worked twice!) like unplugging everything and pressing the power button 15 seconds, or pressing the power button about 10 or 20 times in a few seconds. But now I don't find any way to make it boot.

I wanted to disassemble the computer in order to find if there is a burnt component I could replace, but according to what I understand of the manual, it is very complicated and risky; and hardware is not my cup of tea.

Do you have any idea of what I could do to fix this? (Before I buy a new laptop)

Comment: Sounds like you're in trouble. What is your actual question though?

Comment: What exactly do you believe accumutators are exactly?  It sounds like your laptop is dead and you don't have the skills to fix it yourself.

Comment: @terdon "How to fix this?"

Comment: @Ramhound By accumulators I meant what stores energy. I probably meant "battery", sorry (I'm not a native English speaker)

Comment: @ValentinLorentz - You don't.  You don't have the skills to replace the dead capacitors if they do exist.  I assume you have never removed capacitors in the past.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz - Unless you have 2 batteries its unlike you meant to use the word battery. I believe you meant capacitors since accumulator is an obsolete term or capacitors.  Although the word replacement doesn't work in the second case, but neither does the current word, so I really have no idea what you meant.

Comment: @Ramhound I've heard batteries referred to as accumulators before. It's no longer common in English, but there is precedent for it, and a battery can be regarded as a special case of a capacitor in any case. So quit being picky. :)

Comment: @AaronMiller - Using a modern version of a word is important to communicate on this site.  Based on my research the word is no longer used within the electrical engineering field.  If the user has a dead capacitors thats a whole different problem than a dead laptop battery.

Comment: @Ramhound I am all in favor of lexical strictness, but context matters too, and leniency is in order for someone whose native language is not English, but who nonetheless speaks the language quite well. I can see how you might read "two dead accumutators" as possibly referring to caps -- but "I can still start it on accumutators, but it will probably run out of power in a few minutes"? One never, ever speaks of "starting [a laptop] on capacitors", but one does quite frequently speak of doing so on batteries.

Comment: Just drop it Aaron would you? The author already said he meant his battery in a comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your laptop's power jack may be damaged, so that the connector isn't making proper contact to provide power. (The blink of the LED when you unplug the connector is especially suggestive. Try wiggling the connector while it's plugged into the laptop and see if there is any position in which the LED stays on.)

Replacing a power jack is fairly easy as laptop fixes go. That said, if you're not comfortable taking apart a laptop, I don't recommend trying to do it; it is slow, exacting work with little or no margin for error. Take the computer to a professional for repair, or simply replace it.

Comment: You rock! I already tried it, but I just tried it again and now it works!

Comment: Glad to be of help! If you'd like to return the favor, click the check mark under the vote up/down buttons on my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sure I will, but I have to wait a few seconds. You answered too fast :)

Comment: Gotta have something to do while I wait for my commits to finish. :) Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm, now it shut downs while running, and with the LED still glowing. I'm used to this bug, though; and I can restart it.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there were something else wrong with the laptop, but at least now it's drawing AC power...